# Invalid Character in Path Name

Tags: windows

One of our users is attempting to update their Quickbooks software, as well as install a Blackberry sync software. Both installs fail, citing that there is an invalid/illegal character in the path name- both installers identify this path as "Firstname.Lastname:", which, seeing the colon, makes sense. I Can't identify the rest of the path though, as neither software is telling me what it is.

Microsoft suggests a fix for this issue which involves locating which directories in the registry have this illegal character and then fixing them so that the problem character does not remain- I've tried this to no avail. Another option suggested by microsoft is to attempt the install under a seperate user account; This is not an option either as the software being installed is user specific to the user installing it.

A possible reason for this, as I see it, is that the user's drive has compression enabled. The installs work on other systems with no error, and short of different CPU and RAM, there is no difference in the systems, save for the lack of compression on the system that it works on.

Does anyone know of a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: in the path name of what? the destination, the source? "a fix for this isue": citation? "Firstname.Lastname:" is a string literal or are you anonymizing this? Does the name match exactly with something, such as the user name, or is the name being pulled from some source/database/contact list? Is the blackberry sync software related in any way to quickbooks? What registry entries did you alter?

Comment: I have no idea if that's the path of the destination or the source; my initial suspicion was that the software was trying to write such a directory. That string is definitely anonymized, and yeah, that's the username (the schema in our environment is firstname.lastname)- which is the name of the users folder. Neither software are related in any way. Registry entry modified I forget, but it was the one that determines a users "my photos" directory, as its string had the colon in it after the username.

Comment: OK, so the photos folder is a "magic folder" which has a friendly name and is tied up with domain authentication and redirection. Did you edit the friendly name or the underlying path? Was the underlying path populated with a colon or just the friendly name? Have you verified there is not an actual unicode or hidden character in the domain user name? recall that some unicode characters are control characters which can hide, backspace, render left to right etc.